# Numbers inside a while loop condition

Tags: while-loop, conditional-statements

I know that while(0) means false, while(1) means true, but what if it's while(-3) or other negative values, or while(3) or other positive values? Do they represent true, false, or..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False is Zero, no bits is 1 in binary.

True is 'Not False'. In other words, any numbers except 0 are True.

Answer (score 1):

only `while(0)` is false and any other are true;
That means all nonzero parameter to `while` is true